# Looking for a free SaaS for Text-to-Speech (TTS)

Tags: text-to-speech, saas

I'm looking for a free web-based TTS engine, that I may use in a commercial project. I'm not saying there's one, but I hope somebody might know if there was.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only freely available web-based TTS engine that I am aware of is Google TTS. There is a [blog post](http://weston.ruter.net/projects/google-tts/) on how to use it. The problem with using it commercially is that it is not an official Google API (most solutions to use it have been hacked) and therefore subject to change without notice. For a commercial application I would pay for a good TTS engine. Another option is to get a [freely available TTS engine](http://www.babelfish.org/tts-free.htm) and create your own SaaS.

Comment: Thanks. So I'm pretty much bound to pay for it. Problem is, TTS can be very expensive even if run on my own server...